# Split a string by an entire word, not just one character

Tags: ios, swift, split

I want to split a str by more than one character but I keep getting errors. Is this even possible? A brief search seems to imply it's not.

I want to do something like this:

```
let strspl = "test="
let spl : [String] = str.split(separator: Character(strspl), maxSplits: 1).map(String.init)
```

Error is:

Can't form a Character from a String containing more than one extended grapheme cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [components(separatedBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components) method to get an array of string by separating a string with a string separator

```
var str = "another test= long test"
let strspl = "test="
let spl : [String] = str.components(separatedBy: strspl)
print(spl)
```

> ["another ", " long test"]

Comment: Observe (OP) that this is an NSString method from the Cocoa Foundation. It is _not_ a Swift String method. It works in the presence of the Foundation framework (or UIKit) because String and NSString are toll-free bridged to one another.